# SQL QUERy to Retrieve minimum date for a record with multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

Need help for an Oracle query to retrieve account numbers which has minimum effective date.

For example, I have a table like this;

TABLE A

```
Account_Number  Transaction Number   Effective_Date
1111            001                  01-Jan-2016
1111            002                  01-Feb-2016   
1111            003                  01-Mar-2016  
2222            001                  01-Jun-2016
2222            002                  01-Jul-2016   
2222            003                  01-Aug-2016  
3333            001                  01-Dec-2016
3333            002                  01-Jan-2017   
4444            001                  01-May-2014
4444            002                  01-Jun-2014   
4444            003                  01-Jul-2014
```

Output should be:

```
1111  01-Jan-2016
2222  01-Jun-2016 
3333  01-Dec-2016 
4444  01-May-2014
```

Comment: What have you tried? This should be a very easy exercise, if you don't try it on your own you will never learn SQL.

Comment: this has been answered many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/oracle+greatest-n-per-group

Comment: Trivial homework - show your work!

Comment: spent almost half day...im new to SQL :(

Comment: SELECT ACC_NO, MIN (EFF_DATE) FROM TABLE A GROUP BY ACCT_NO,EFF_DATE.

Comment: @RAO why did you answer your own question in a comment? You are allowed to put it as an answer if you want...

Comment: Oops, baby to this forum :(

Comment: @RAO remove EFF_DATE from GROUP BY and you should be fine

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need the `MIN()` function.  If your question is more complicated than this, please clarify.

```
select Acct_No, min(Eff_Date) 
from The_Table
group by Acct_No
```

Comment: I had same query, its not giving me min value for the account :( .its displaying all rows..

Comment: No, it will give you 1 row for each unique value of Acct_No - that's what `GROUP BY` does

Comment: Don't group by Acct_No, Eff_Date! Only group by Acct_No